# Power BI update make refers to other queries

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to manually update my Power BI report and when I click on reload button, this message appear,

> Query 'VW_INS_MC_ITEMS' (step 'Extracted First Characters') refers to other queries or steps, so you cannot access the data source directly. Re-generate this data combination.

I have already verified the connections, permissions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File - Options and Settings - Options - Current File - Privacy
and select **Ignore the Privacy Levels**

[image]